# How do I add errror handling into this stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I print an error message from this procedure if the employee (server) hasn't served anyone? Are `try - catch` blocks the only way to handle this?

I was thinking that if/else condition test followed by `Print` message suits my requirement.

Stored procedure:

```
if OBJECT_ID('customers_served', 'u') is not null
    drop procedure customers_served;
go

create procedure customers_served
    @employee_id int
as 
    set nocount on;

    select 
        c.customer_id, c.cust_lastname, 
        (sum(c.cust_total_guests)) as total_guests
    from 
        customers c
    join 
        seating s on c.customer_id = s.customer_id
    join 
        table_assignment ta on s.table_id = ta.table_id
    join 
        employees e on ta.employee_id = e.employee_id
    where 
        @employee_id = e.employee_id
    group by 
        c.customer_id, c.cust_lastname;

/* if total_guests = 0 print message the employee has served 0 guests */
```

Test procedure:

```
exec customers_served
        @employee_id = 5;
```

Comment: "Print an error message" to somewhere rather than [`RaIsError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql) or [`Throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql) an exception? You can use [`Print`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql) with `if`, or simply return the result set to the application and let it handle it as needed.

Comment: yeah, just something simple for now as I learn more about the Raiserror and Throw.

Comment: so i could use an if total_guests = 0   Print 'This server did not serve any guests';

Comment: Assuming that the query returns one row you would want something like: (1) output the results to a temporary table ([`select ... into #Results`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql)), (ii) check the sum (`if ( select total_guests from #Results ) = 0 print 'Slacker!'`), and (C) return the results (`select * from #Results`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your script to this.

```
use dbServers;

if OBJECT_ID('customers_served', 'u') is not null
drop procedure customers_served;
go

create procedure customers_served
@employee_id    int
as 
set nocount on;

declare @totalGuests int;

set @totalGuests = (
 select(sum(c.cust_total_guests))
 from customers c
 join seating s on c.customer_id = s.customer_id
 join table_assignment ta on s.table_id = ta.table_id
 join employees e on ta.employee_id = e.employee_id
 where @employee_id = e.employee_id
)

if @totalGuests = 0 OR @totalGuests IS NULL
BEGIN
 print 'This server did not serve any guests'
END
else
BEGIN
 select @totalGuests AS 'total_quests'
END

/* test procedure*/
exec customers_served
@employee_id = 5;
```

Comment: both scripts are clean. declaring a variable and testing isn't where i was thinking. Thanks for the effort and responses...the logic makes perfect sense.

Comment: Or `select @TotalGuests = sum...`. In any event, this doesn't result the other columns from the query in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Following snippet of code might help:

```
declare @r int

select @r = (sum(c.cust_total_guests)) as  total_guests
from customers c
join seating s on c.customer_id = s.customer_id
join table_assignment ta on s.table_id = ta.table_id
join employees e on ta.employee_id = e.employee_id
where @employee_id = e.employee_id
group by c.customer_id, c.cust_lastname;

if @r = 0
begin
-- do what ever you wish
end
else
begin
select c.customer_id, c.cust_lastname, (sum(c.cust_total_guests)) as      
       total_guests
from customers c
join seating s on c.customer_id = s.customer_id
join table_assignment ta on s.table_id = ta.table_id
join employees e on ta.employee_id = e.employee_id
where @employee_id = e.employee_id
group by c.customer_id, c.cust_lastname;
end 
end
```

Comment: Since there is only one row returned, just select all of the columns into variables. (`select @Customer_Id = c.Customer_Id, @Cust_LastName = c.Cust_LastName, ...`.) Then the final result is returned with a simple `select @Customer_Id as Customer_Id, @Cust_LastName as Cust_LastName, @r as Total_Guests`. No need to repeat the query.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than double querying, you can simply test @@ROWCOUNT after your query to determine if any results were returned, and print your message if @@ROWCOUNT = 0.

Comment: `@@RowCount` returns the number of rows returned by the `select`, not the value of `sum(c.cust_total_guests)`.